# не получается использование ejs внутри js script

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

использую шаблонизатор ejs на node.js
возникла проблема использования ejs внутри js script, ну или методика использования внутри script совсем другая. но проблема заключается в том что не получается вывести данные которые нужно с помощью innerHTML показать в клиенте

```
<script>
  let category = document.getElementById('category')
  let subcategoryForm = document.getElementById('subcategory')

  category.addEventListener('change', (event) =>{
    subcategoryForm.innerHTML = '<option selected>Выберите субкатегорию...</option>'
    let _id = event.target.value
    fetch(`/genres/subcategory/${_id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(subcategory =>{
      subcategory.forEach(sub =>{
        console.log(sub);
        subcategoryForm.innerHTML += `
          <option value="<%= sub._id %>"><%= sub.title %></option>
        `
      })
    })
  })

</script>
```

не подскажите какой подходи будет правильным?

Comment: EJS для html, а тут чистый JS. Воспользуйтесь [String Substitution](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/es6-template-strings/#string-substitution)

Comment: изначально делал так как вы говорите, <option value="${sub._id}>">${sub.title}</option>
но оно не работало, и вот я тут что бы понять как всё это устроено